# how to change `this` pointer in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, image

I want to create a Image data and rewrite onload function , but `this` can't point to `newImage` in typescript. what can i do to make `this` pointer point to `newImage`

[image]

Comment: https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/typeguard

Comment: just use `newImg` which should work due to closures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can tell TypeScript which type `this` should have by adding it as a function parameter:

```
function onload(this: HTMLImageElement) {
  const {width, height} = this
}
```

The parameter will be ignored when compiling to JavaScript.

See https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#declaring-this-in-a-function

Answer (score 0):

According to the code you provided I do not see a way to use `this` pointer as `newImg`.
But you will be able to use `const{width,height} = newImg.somethingYouWannaDo()`.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function onload(img){
  const {width, height} = img
}
```

Isn't onload passed the img?